# Insert into mongo 2 objects

Tags: c#, mongodb

Hi I am trying to insert into a mongoDB 2 objects. 
When I insert 1 object it works fine,

```
private void Query<TO>(TO o)
{
    const string connectionString = "mongodb://localhost";
    var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
    var server = client.GetServer();
    var database = server.GetDatabase("test");
    var collection = database.GetCollection<TO>(o.GetType().Name + "s");
    collection.Insert(o);
}
```

but when I try to insert 2 objects , the BSON driver thows an error

```
private void Query<TO, TK, TV>(TO o, Dictionary<TK, TV> ExtraFields)
{
    const string connectionString = "mongodb://localhost";
    var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
    var server = client.GetServer();
    var database = server.GetDatabase("test");
    var collection = database.GetCollection<Object[]>(o.GetType().Name + "s");
    collection.Insert(new List<object>
    {
        o,
        ExtraFields
    });
}
```

the error I get is

> {"Serializer EnumerableSerializer expected serialization
>   options of type ArraySerializationOptions, not
>   DocumentSerializationOptions."}

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using `collection.InsertBatch()` instead?

Comment: You should probably be using [InsertBatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-csharp-driver/#insertbatch-method), rather than Insert as Insert expects a single object not an enumerable, whereas InsertBatch will accept an enumerable.

Comment: Yes , got another error  {"Serializer DictionarySerializer<String, String> expected serialization options of type DictionarySerializationOptions, not DocumentSerializationOptions."}

Answer (score 0):

Your collection type needs to be a class and can't be an array or collection.  Not sure if you're trying to treat your "2 objects" as one document or insert them as separate items.  You either need to create a class to hold them or build the BsonDocument on your own and store them that way.  I don't think you can use generics the way you're doing as well.
Something like this:

```
public class ObjectWithExtraFields {
    public Type1 O { get; set; }        
    public Dictionary<string, Type2> ExtraFields { get; set; }
}

var collection = database.GetCollection<ObjectWithExtraFields>(o.GetType().Name + "s");
collection.Insert(new ObjectWithExtraFields {    
    O = o,
    ExtraFields = ExtraFields
});
```